# Text Files Are Downloading In ANSI Instead Of UTF-8 Bom

Tags: text, encoding, utf-8, ansi, turkish

If i try to download any text, srt, or exe program, it is downloading in ANSI encoding instead of UTF-8 Bom encoding. I'm Turkish user. Some of Turkish characters like ı, ş, İ, ğ has been showing as ý, þ, ð

For example Internet Download Manager uses lang files as text. Some Turkish characters are broken.

Windows language is totally Turkish. I bought the laptop from USA.

How can i fix this problem? Please help me.

I FIXED BY EDITING ADMINISTRATOR LANGUAGE SETTINGS.
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy7sw.jpg)

Comment: When you say "showing as", what application do you use to display those characters?

Comment: Usually (but on old time with FTP), download is transparent. So probably the original file were "ANSI". Check with a browser (and there you can debug also the header)

Comment: @Sabuncu Internet Download Manager as program. Most of text files like srt subtitles, standard txt files as text files.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi if i download same file from other device, file is in utf8-bom. how can i fix this on my laptop? Also not from ftp. downloading anywhere on the net.

Comment: When you open the srt file in Notepad.exe, what do you see?

Comment: This site is for programmer. If you want to fix your laptop, you should go to the relevant sister site (e.g. superuser). Your question is not related on programming, so probably it is only a program problem, and programmers hate bad programs (and we tend to use other programs than other people, so it is also more difficult to help).

Comment: original files were UTF-8, not ANSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by editing administrator language settings.

[image: Fixing the issue]